# The three Cs - spices with chicken

Tags: spices, herbs

I watched a TV programme that was talking about a particular combination of three spices which are often used together, especially with chicken.

The TV presenter said that they were used together so often that they were referred to as 'the three Cs'.

I know one of them is cumin, but I can't remember the other two.

Does anyone know what they might be?

Comment: http://www.food.com/recipe/three-cs-chicken-citrus-chilli-and-coriander-299706? Or this one: http://www.nigella.com/recipes/view/three-cs-chicken-1616 Or this one: http://picniconthird.com/blog/dishes/3-cs-rubbed-chicken/ (I'm guessing this last one is more likely the one you're looking for?)

Comment: Sorry I keep commenting but it seems like everyone has a different list of three "cs" for chicken.  There's a [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=xCA2GudEI6QC&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=three+c%27s+with+chicken+cumin&source=bl&ots=50cRGjIbQ8&sig=qdFtuSkfgo5fc9giWRQJSYZD6yU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBWoVChMIkp_m3c_5xgIVQu2ACh0aSw0C#v=onepage&q=three%20c%27s%20with%20chicken%20cumin&f=false) that lists cinnamon, coriander and cumin. Another place lists cumin, coriander and cayenne... and another that replaces the cayenne with cardamom...

Comment: So, I can pretty much bet that two of them are cumin and coriander... the third one seems to depend on what sort of flavor you're looking for.

Comment: @Catija - wow, thanks! I didn't expect an answer so fast! Yes, it seems that one of them is definitely coriander. I wonder if the original that I heard was cardamom

Comment: Just the power of Google, to be honest. If you're looking for a nice, subtle flavor, cardamom would be a very classic choice, just don't try to eat a whole pod, it's very bitter.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks. Are there no other c herbs that might fit the bill?

Comment: @Catija these comments are sufficient for a full answer! It's much better to put even partial answers into the answers than to make them as comments.

Comment: Those are spices and not herbs with the exception of coriander which can come as a herb (the leaves) and a spice (the seeds). If the recipe was 3 spice chicken then @Catija has probably answered, however if the recipe is for herbs than it's not right.

Comment: Good point @GdD. I'll amend the question.

Comment: What was the cuisine that the program was showing @Charon? The 3 Cs will vary depending on the answer.

Comment: I know, I just can't remember! From the way that the presenter had said it, I presumed that 'the three Cs' was a constant and well-known combination, hence my question. Apparently however, it's neither of those things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, it depends on the sort of cuisine you're talking about.

However, there is a very common "chord" of three spices, which is popular in Greece, Turkey, Arab cultures, Indian cooking genres and even China.

That "chord" is Cumin, Coriander seed and Cardamom. It's definitely used with chicken, but is also applied to plenty of vegetarian dishes as well.